# Integrate with an other measure than Lebesgue

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $\mu : \mathbb{B(\mathbb{R})} \to \mathbb{R}$ such as $$\forall A \in \mathbb{R},\, \mu(A) = \frac{1}{4}\int_A e^{-|x|} \, \mathrm{d}x \, + \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{1}_A(0)$$

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a positive Borel function.

I followed a course on Measure Theory but we never integrated with something else than Lebesgue measure. I'm now doing a probability exercice in which I have to give a formula in order to calculate $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\, \mathrm{d}\mu(x)$. I have the answer right in front of my eyes but still can't manage to understand how we integrate with respect to $\mu$

EDIT : Is it correct ? :
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\, \mathrm{d}\mu(x) = \require{cancel}\cancel{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\mu(\{x\})\, \mathrm{d}x} = \frac{1}{4}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-|x|}\,dx +\frac{1}{2}f(0)$$

Comment: The measure in your problems is $\mu(dx)=\frac14 e^{-|x|}\,dx +\frac12\delta_0(dx)$. For any Positive Borel function $f$, $$\int f\,d\mu=\frac14\int_\mathbb{R}f(x) e^{-|x|}\,dx +\frac12f(0)$$ Whenever you have two measures $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ on a measure space $(X,\mathscr{B})$ and $f:X\mathbb{R}_+$ is measurable $$\int_X f d(\nu_1+\nu_2)=\int_X f\,d\nu_1 +\int_X f\,d\nu_2$$

Comment: Your question is a little vague, If you have a more specific question, let me know. You can review basic integration on the appendix to say, Durrret's probability theory book.

Comment: Hint: First try integrating when $f$ is a simple function.  Then try to extend that formula to measurable functions, and prove that it works by taking limits.

Comment: thanks for your answers, however i still don't understand how you obtain $\int d\mu$. if you can explain it to me it would be great @OliverDiaz

Comment: I edited my post, can you tell me if it's how we should get it ?

Comment: @YassineB. Is you have to measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, then the sum $\mu_1+\mu_2$ is the measure defined by $(\mu_1+\mu_2)(A)=\mu_1(A)+\mu_2(A)$ (you can check that this is indeed a measure). From sets, you can move to (positive) simple functions in the usual way: $\int\phi d(\mu_1+\mu_2)=\int\phi\,d\mu_1 +\int\phi\,d\mu_2$. From simple functions you move onto measurable positive functions by the usual monotone approximation arguments to get $\int f d(\mu_1+\mu_2)=\int f\,d\mu_1+\int f\,d\mu_2$. Then you owe onto general functions $f=f_+-f_-$ for which $|f|$ is integrable.

Comment: the definition of Lebesgue integral of a nonnegative measurable function $f$ is $\inf f\,d\mu=\inf\{\int \phi:\phi\leq f\}$ where the infimum is taken over nonnegative simple functions.

Comment: Not correct: $\int f\,d\mu$ can be denoted as $\int f\,\mu(dx)$ or even $\int f\,d\mu(x)$. That is different from $\int f(x)\mu(\{x\})\,dx$ in which the function you are integrating (with respect to Lebesgue Measure presumably) is $x\mapsto f(x)\mu(\{x\})$. $\int f\,d\mu$, namely $\inf\{\int\phi\,d\mu:0\leq\phi\leq f\}$ where infimum is taken over simple functions.